# Jasmine sbt plugin not executing tests

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, jasmine

I am trying to use the sbt-jasmine-plugin based on and referring to http://perevillega.com/post/2013/01/26/26/executing-jasmine-tests-in-play-204/. However after all configuration done and errors fixed, play test runs successfully but without executing any testcases.

Logs:
[info] running jasmine...
See https://github.com/jrburke/r.js for usage.
[  Envjs/1.6 (Rhino; U; Mac OS X x86_64 10.9.2; en-US; rv:1.7.0.rc2) Resig/20070309 PilotFish/1.2.13  ]
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active

Passed: 0
Failed: 0
Total : 0

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.gu.SbtJasminePlugin._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val appName         = "webapp"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

// Project dependencies
val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    anorm,
    javaJpa,
    filters,
    jdbc    
)

lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
.settings(jasmineSettings : _*)
.settings(      
    appJsDir <+= baseDirectory / "public/javascripts/app",
    appJsLibDir <+= baseDirectory / "public/javascripts/vendor",
    jasmineTestDir <+= baseDirectory / "test/js",
    jasmineConfFile <+= baseDirectory / "test/jasmineDependencies.js",
    (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (jasmine)
    )  
}
```

Plugin.scala:

```
import sbt._

object Plugins extends Build {
   lazy val plugins = Project("plugins", file("."))
.dependsOn(uri("https://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin.git#0.7"))
}
```

Dependency file:

```
// Dependencies for the unit test via Jasmine
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "/../jquery-1.7.1.min.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "jquery-ui.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "jquery.tmpl.min.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "/angular/1.2.0rc1/angular.js");
EnvJasmine.loadGlobal(EnvJasmine.libDir + "/angular/1.2.0rc1/angular-resource.min.js");
```

sample testSpec.js:

```
describe('Hello world', function() {    
it('says hello', function() {
    expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
});
});
```

the folder structure for test is: webapp/test/js/specs/

Not sure where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i figured this out. It relates to the name of the test file. I had it earlier as testSpec.js and now i renamed it to test.spec.js. This time with "play test" i am able to execute the test case. i was thinking it will run all the cases in the test directory that was specified but not sure of it expects a certain file name format.

Comment: Yep, many of us have hit this same issue.  I recently updated the readme's [Config](https://github.com/barnesjd/sbt-jasmine-plugin#configuration) section in hopes of helping people not hit this issue.